# Imported a file but it says module not found

Tags: python, python-import

So i have the issue that i imported a file "DB.py", but if i try to run my program it says that the module wasnt found.
[See this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UeYIN.png)

[This is how in imported the file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N3DP0.png)

I already tried to change the file name n stuff but nothing rly works.

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of error messages or code. Instead, copy/paste your code into the post editor and code format it so others can reproduce your problem. Also, please include your directory structure as text if possible.

Comment: By the way: It is encouraged to type out or copy paste errors or code in stack overflow and reserve images for diagrams or things that are hard to explain in words.

Answer (score 0):

You need a blank python file named `__init__.py` in the directory that has `DB.py`. It tells python that there is a python module in that directory.